# ¿Como crear un servidor para manejar los parámetros obtenidos con GET/POST en python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Poseo un servidor en `python3` con los métodos `get` y `post`, quisiera poder obtener los valores de las variables pasadas y mostrarlos en el formulario.

Para probar las peticiones utilice POSTMAN.

```
#!C:/Python36/python.exe
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

# BHRH --> handle the HTTP requests that arrive at the server (GET / POST)
# HTTPServer -->  This class builds on the TCPServer create
# server address as instance variables named server_name and server_port.

# HTTPRequestHandler class
class HTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        rootdir = "c:/xampp/htdocs/"
        try:
            #if self.path.endswith('.html'):
            filePath = self.path
            print(filePath)
            file = open(rootdir + self.path)
            fileContent = file.read()
            self._set_headers()
            # WFILE => Contains the output stream for writing a response back to the client.
            self.wfile.write(fileContent.encode("UTF-8"))
            #return
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404, 'file not found')

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        # <--- Gets the size of data
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        # <--- Gets the data itself
        # Contains an input stream, positioned at the start of the optional input data.
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(post_data)
        #print(post_data)

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=HTTPServer_RequestHandler):
    print('starting server...')
    # Server settings
    # Choose port 8080, for port 80, which is normally used for a http server, you need root access
    server_address = ('localhost', 8081)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, HTTPServer_RequestHandler)
    print('running server...')
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener un servidor funcional con el cual puedas manejar los query params de GET y POST debes tener la siguiente configuracion:

```
#!C:/Python36/python.exe
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import urllib
from urllib.parse import *

# BHRH --> handle the HTTP requests that arrive at the server (GET / POST)
# HTTPServer -->  This class builds on the TCPServer create
# server address as instance variables named server_name and server_port.

# HTTPRequestHandler class
class HTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def doPathParse(self,path):
        parsePath = urlparse(path)
        filePath = parsePath.path
        fileQuery = parsePath.query
        fileDecode = urllib.parse.parse_qs(fileQuery)
        result = {"parse":parsePath, "path":filePath , "query": fileQuery, "decodeQuery": fileDecode}
        return result

    def doPrintPostAll(self,post_data):
        for key, value in post_data.items():
            self.wfile.write(bytes(key+" = ","UTF-8"))

            for data in value:
                self.wfile.write(bytes(data,"UTF-8"))

    def doPrintPostSpecified(self,key,post_data):
        for data in post_data[key]:
            self.wfile.write(bytes(data,"UTF-8"))

    def doPrintGetAll(self,get_data):
        for key, value in get_data.items():
            self.wfile.write(bytes(key+" = ","UTF-8"))

            for data in value:
                self.wfile.write(bytes(data,"UTF-8"))

    def doPrintGetSpecified(self,key,get_data):
        for data in get_data[key]:
            self.wfile.write(bytes(data,"UTF-8"))

    def do_GET(self):
        rootdir = "c:/xampp/htdocs/"
        try:
            path = self.path

            pathParse = self.doPathParse(path)

            filePath = pathParse["path"]

            fileQuery = pathParse["query"]

            fileDecode = pathParse["decodeQuery"]

            file = open(rootdir + filePath)

            fileContent = file.read()

            self._set_headers()
            # WFILE => Contains the output stream for writing a response back to the client.
            self.wfile.write(bytes(fileContent,"UTF-8"))
            # --- METER EN UNA CLASE --- #
            #self.doPrintGetSpecified("getParam",fileDecode)


        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404, 'file not found')

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        path = self.path
        # <--- Gets the size of data
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        # <--- Gets the data itself
        # Usamos decode para eliminar el b' del tipo binary
        # Usamos parse_qs para generar un diccionario con los datos POSTeados
        post_data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(content_length).decode('utf-8'))
        # rfile Contains an input stream, positioned at the start of the optional input data.
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Hola</p>","UTF-8"))

        # --- METER EN UNA CLASE --- #
        #self.doPrintPostSpecified("postParam",post_data)


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=HTTPServer_RequestHandler):
    print('starting server...')
    # Server settings
    # Choose port 8080, for port 80, which is normally used for a http server, you need root access
    server_address = ('localhost', 8081)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, HTTPServer_RequestHandler)
    print('running server...')
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```